# Logstash RabbitMQ input plugin - How to define multiple routing_key

Tags: rabbitmq, logstash

I'm using RabbitMQ plugin of Logstash to pull from RabbitMQ and push to Elasticsearch using this pipeline:

```
input {
    rabbitmq {
        queue => "Elasticsearch_Queue"
        host => "rabbitmq"
        exchange => "my_event_bus"
        key => "SomeIntegrationEvent"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "elasticsearch:9200" ]
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

It works fine and creates a queue named `Elasticsearch_Queue` and binds to `my_event_bus` exchange using routing_key `SomeIntegrationEvent`.

I need to **subscribe to multiple events** but there is no clear solution on the [plugin docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-rabbitmq.html#plugins-inputs-rabbitmq-key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to add multiple entries with same `queue` and `exchange` but different `key`, as below:

```
input {
    rabbitmq {
        queue => "Elasticsearch_Queue"
        host => "rabbitmq"
        exchange => "my_event_bus"
        key => "SomeIntegrationEvent1"
    }
    rabbitmq {
        queue => "Elasticsearch_Queue"
        host => "rabbitmq"
        exchange => "my_event_bus"
        key => "SomeIntegrationEvent2" 
    }
}
```

I got [the answer](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-rabbitmq-input-plugin-how-to-define-multiple-routing-key/183817/2) from elastic forums.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [`key`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-rabbitmq.html#plugins-inputs-rabbitmq-key) must be a string, you can't explicitly bind the queue to the exchange using multiple keys.

I suggest to make `my_event_bus` a **fanout exchange**. This will route every message delivered into this exchange to the bound queue.

Then define a second **direct exchange** that you manually bind to the first exchange multiple times using the routing keys (= events) you are interested in.

Comment: If I want to manually bind queues then I prefer to manually bind my `Elasticsearch_Queue` to multiple routing_keys. I think your solution complicate the scenario. I wish there was a solution for multiple routing_keys.

Comment: Well, the documentation tells us that there is no such solution. You could ask the developers of the logstash plugin if they can add the feature you are missing.